# Flutter camera selection for website at aplication level

Tags: flutter, webview, permissions, camera, mediacapture

I'm trying to make flutter browser for Android in which when websites ask for camera permission then user can select the camera (front, back) in it.

Opera Android browser have same feature so it is possible to do in Android.

How to change media capture device at aplication level for website in flutter?